# Corona SDK getting the name of the font used

Tags: fonts, lua, coronasdk

I am having a problem, might seem like a wierd question to you, since there might not be alot of sense with it.

Anyway, I am displaying a short story on 3 scenes in a storyboard, (Its actually Fresh Prince in Bel Air lyrics, dont ask why. ;) ) which all have different fonts.

Now I want to make a button, so that when i press it, I want the application to "fetch" the current font used, and display it.

The button and listeners etc. is not a problem, got that covered. But how do i "fetch" the fontname? I do not want to use a variable and just save the name as a string there. I want the program to find the name of it.

Hope this makes any sense. Thank you! / Joakim

Comment: Current font for *what*. Different objects can have different fonts.

Comment: Just the font for a newText.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just do:

```
 local someText = display.newText("Hello World", 0, 0, "Helvetica", 32)
```

then I don't see a way to get to the font that text is using.  However if you do:

```
 local someText = display.newText("Hello World", 0, 0, "Helvetica", 32)
 someText.font = "Helvetica"
```

That will change the font, in this case to Helvetica, which is what it already is and then you can simply look at that property:

```
 print(someText.font)
```

to get the font.  That is not set if you do the first method.  But at the end of the day, you are setting a variable.  In this case, its part of the object instead of a separate table.

Comment: Thank you! I think I just misunderstood my task to be honest. What teachers were after was that he wanted us to explore native.getFontNames(). Just for us to realise that the font name and the filename wasnt always the same.